# Is there a way to find the minimum value across multiple data frames?

Tags: r

I have around 20 data frames that have the exact same format and dimensions with six columns. The only difference between each data frame is the different values in the sixth column. I want to run a loop through all the data frames so that I can get the minimum value across all data frames for the sixth column. My plan is to list all the data frames in a vector and then loop through the vector and then loop through each line of the data frames, though I'm not sure how I can implement something like that. I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: To clarify: do you want the minimum value per data frame (20 values), or the minimum value overall (1 value) ?

Comment: *"The only difference between each data frame is the different values in the sixth column."* Then it's better to keep the (five) common columns in one dataframe, and the differing column in one (or twenty) separate dataframe. You can join them with `cbind` or `join`.

Comment: You could just calculate the min of column six for each data.frame, and then take the min of those 20 mins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data frames are DF1, DF2, ..., DF20 then assuming you want the data frame DF such that DF[i, j] = min(DF1[i, j], DF2[i, j], ..., DF20[i, j]) then:

```
L <- list(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4, DF5, DF6, DF7, DF8, DF9, DF10,
          DF11, DF12, DF13, DF14, DF15, DF16, DF17, DF18, DF19, DF20)
Reduce(pmin, L)
```

or

```
do.call(pmin, L)
```

or

```
pmin(DF1, DF2, DF3, DF4, DF5, DF6, DF7, DF8, DF9, DF10,
          DF11, DF12, DF13, DF14, DF15, DF16, DF17, DF18, DF19, DF20)
```

We can get `L` in a number of ways other than writing it out:

1. if we have the names of the data frames in a character vector `Names` then `L <- mget(Names, .GlobalEnv)` and if we knew that the data frames all have names `DF` followed by digits then we can form `Names` using `Names <- ls(pattern = "^DF\\d+$")`
2. if the only data frames in the global environment are DF1, DF2, ..., DFn then we can form `L` like this:

   ```
   m <- mget(ls(), envir = .GlobalEnv, mode = "list", ifnotfound = NA)
   L <- Filter(is.data.frame, m)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to find the minimum values considering only the last (6th) column across all your dataframes, then here is a solution:

```
DF <- rbind (df1, df2, ..., df20)  # Combine data frames, vertically
last_col <- DF [, ncol(DF)]        # Only care about 6th column
min(last_col)
```